# binomial test in R using by() on data.frame

Tags: r, function, apply

I'm confused about the behavior of `binom.test` when used in the `by` option.

It doesn't seem to be working for some dataframes, but works with some dummy data that I put together.

Calling `mean()` works as it should though...

My example code is below.

---

```
#####  this does not work...

bug <- InsectSprays   
bug$outcome <- ifelse(bug$count > 4, 1, 2 )
bug$spray.n <- ifelse(bug$spray == "A", 1,
               ifelse(bug$spray == "B", 2,
               ifelse(bug$spray == "C", 3,
               ifelse(bug$spray == "D", 4,
               ifelse(bug$spray == "E", 5, 6)))))

binom.test(table(bug$outcome), alternative="greater")               
by(bug, bug$spray.n, FUN = function(X) binom.test(table(X$outcome),
  alternative="greater" ))
by(bug, bug$spray.n, FUN = function(X) mean(X$count)                             

#####  this works...

#####  generating example data
#####  this has three groups, each with a binomial indicator
#####  success is coded as 1, failure as a 0

set.seed(271828)
center <- gl(3,10)
outcome <- rbinom(length(center), 1, .6777)
id <- seq(1,length(center),1)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(center,id,outcome))

#####  have to recode success and failure to use table()  
#####  !!!!! would like to avoid having to do this...

dat$primary <- ifelse(dat$outcome == 1 , 1 , 2)
dat$cent <- as.factor(dat$center)

##### carrying out one sided binomial test for positive outcome

binom.test(table(dat$primary), alternative = "greater" )

#####  would like to carry out the same test by center...

by(dat, dat$center, FUN = function(X) binom.test(table(X$primary), 
  alternative = "greater"))
by(dat, dat$center, FUN = function(X) mean(X$outcome))
```

Comment: You might see a problem if you try: `by(bug, bug$spray.n, FUN = function(X) table(X$outcome))`

Comment: It is discourteous to slip in `rm( list=ls() )` without a warning or comment.

Comment: @DWin Sorry about that, snuck in when I wasn't paying close attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem if you try:

`by(bug, bug$spray.n, FUN = function(X) table(X$outcome))`

Answer (score 2):

THe reason that some of the `binom.test` calls were not working is because some of the groups have all successes (or failures).  So, you need at least two levels in every group in order to do the test (which makes total sense...).

---

For completeness:

```
           #####  this does work...

           air <- airquality
           air

           air$outcome <- ifelse(air$Wind > 10, 1, 2 )


           binom.test(table(air$outcome), alternative="greater")



           by(air, air$Month, FUN = function(X) mean(X$Wind))

           by(air, air$Month, FUN = function(X) table(X$outcome))

           by(air, air$Month, FUN = function(X) binom.test(table(X$outcome), alternative="greater"))
```

Comment: +1 Your additional explanation makes it more useful for others.